# PCF / Cloud connector for Rabbit management API

Tags: rabbitmq, pcf, spring-cloud-connectors

All,
I'm running a simple SpringBoot app in PCF using a Rabbit on-demand service. The auto reconfiguration of the ConnectionFactory for the internal Rabbit service works just fine.

However I need a list of all queues on the Rabbit host. AFAIK this is only available through a call to the Rabbit management plugin (a REST API), see RabbitManagementTemplate::getQueues. This class expects an http URI with credentials.
I know the URI+credentials are exposed through the vcap.service variables as "http_api_uri', but I wonder if there's a more elegant way to get an instance of RabbitManagentTemplate with Spring magic cloud connectors / auto reconfiguration instead of manually reading the env vars and writing custom bean config.

It seems the ConnectionFactory only knows about the AMQP interface, and cannot create a RabbitManagementTemplate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Connectors won't help you here. It doesn't support setting up `RabbitManagementTemplate`, only a `ConnectionFactory`.

You don't have to parse the env yourself, you can use the flattened properties that [Boot provides](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html) such as `vcap.services.rabbitmq.credentials.http_api_uri`. But you'll need to configure a `RabbitManagementTemplate` yourself using those Boot properties.